# paypal order summary missing

Tags: php, paypal

For checking out process while redirecting the user  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com the paypal does not show more than one type item and only the last (with its quantity) i.e, if user add two types product in his cart and click for checking out process the paypal show only the second type with its quantity but not the first type in billing process. how can i solve the problem?
here is my api code in view file

```
     <form style=" padding:0px;margin:0px;" name="frmOrderAutoSubmit" method="post" >


        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sunymegh@gmail.com">
                    <?php $cdata = $this->cart->contents() ?>
                    <?php foreach ($cdata as $items) { ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $items['qty']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=" <?php echo $items['name']; ?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $items['price']; ?>"/>

                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
                    <input TYPE="hidden" name="address_override" value="0">

                         <?php } ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have one `name` attribute submitted `name="quantity"` for example.  PayPal uses a format of `name="quantity_1"`.